# Passing additional information to errors handled by `redux-actions`

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-actions

[redux-actions](https://redux-actions.js.org/api/createaction#createactiontype)
handles errors "automatically":

> if the payload is an instance of an Error object, redux-actions will
>   automatically set action.error to true

And the error will be the payload of this action.

But if the payload is made of the error, how can I extract information from this
action in my reducer to mark the related item as "on error" (except by
extracting information from the error message) ?

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions'
import * as api from '../api'

export const fetchSomethingRequest = createAction('FETCH_SOMETHING_REQUEST')
export const fetchSomethingResponse = createAction('FETCH_SOMETHING_RESPONSE')

export const fetchSomething = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchSomethingRequest({ id }))

  return api
    .fetchSomething(id)
    .then(something => dispatch(fetchSomethingResponse({ id, something })))
    // I would like to add some information to be able afterwards (eg. in a
    // reducer) to mark `id` as on error
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchSomethingResponse(error)))
    // with regular actions, I would do something like this
    // .catch(error => dispatch(fetchSomethingResponse({ id, error }))) 
}
```

I guess I could use the `meta` information of the action, but I think there's something I'm missing here.

Note: 
[Flux Standard Action](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action) thinks of errors as a [first class concept](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action#errors-as-a-first-class-concept):

> Flux actions can be thought of as an asynchronous sequence of values. It is
>   important for asynchronous sequences to deal with errors. Currently, many Flux
>   implementations don't do this, and instead define separate action types like
>   LOAD_SUCCESS and LOAD_FAILURE. This is less than ideal, because it overloads
>   two separate concerns: disambiguating actions of a certain type from the
>   "global" action sequence, and indicating whether or not an action represents an
>   error. FSA treats errors as a first class concept.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing an error to action creator, error object should be accessible via `action.payload`, while `action.error` is just a boolean flag which is signalizing that payload is error.

You also can inherit default Error to store additional data:

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message, payload) {
    super(message);
    this.payload = payload
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with `the error will be the payload of this action`. What I don't know is how to extract information from this payload, or from the action in general (eg. which `id` this error is related to).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteRudant Oh, I see, for this you have to explicitly define your action payload like you mentioned in a comment inside of your code: fetchSomethingResponse({ id, error })

Comment: Thank you @eugene-tsakh. But by doing that I'm ignoring the concept of errors as "first class concept", and I don't see many use cases for the default behavior of `redux-actions` when they are passed an error (most of the time, I need to know more about the error).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteRudant you can also use your custom errors. Added more info to my answer